# Pull images from foursquare venues into merged photo-stream

Tags: foursquare

Would it be possible (using an API), to pull all images from users' checkins at venues and feed them onto screens around different physical locations and also to a website? Ideally, the images would be pulled live as they're uploaded from the venue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The API call venues/VENUE_ID/photos will let you get photos for a venue. Additionally, using the "group" parameter will allow you to either retrieve photos added by friends (including on their recent checkins) or retrieve public photos added to the venue by non-friends. Creating an AJAX request to the API response would allow you to gather the photos in what would appear to be real time ( or very close to it ).